# Should we normalize validation set as well as test dataset using same parametes from train data (LSTM in Keras)?

Tags: validation, keras, lstm, normalization

Suppose that we have three data-sets: Train, validation, and test. We know that we should use the parameters extracted from normalization of train data for normalizing test data. Also, we know that validation is a part of train data (following the structure of Keras). Should we also normalize validation set with same parameters extracted from train data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missing something: Yes, why wouldn't you want to use the same parameters?

Comment: So this is the procedure; Normalize train data, use the same parameter extracted from train data separately for validation and test dataset. Is it correct?

Comment: @user2991243 I believe so.